# Transforming Data into a timeline

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, find

Im trying to transform my data that currently looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b42fb.png)

What I want it transformed into is for each User I want a timeline as to what process occurred first and when. Such as:
[image]

I was attempting to use the find function with a loop running through each user and then just putting the times adjacent to each corresponding user. But I cannot figure out how to get the find function to run multiple times after finding the first occurrence but also finding the minimum and then second minimum time etc...

Im open to other suggestions for VBA

Comment: How are you merging Process A User and Process B user into one column called User?  Can't see how that works. Use the actual data sample at the top to show how it fits when in desired outcome format. And look into using tools like [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) rather than images of data. People can't copy paste from the image for testing.

Comment: I am looking to make a unique list of users that will be performing multiple tasks. So it would just be looking at what tasks User A performed and at what times. Sorry should have named the processes something different to remove confusion that the processes are not restricted to each user.  @QHarr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means perfect but it gives you a foundation to work on.

The logic is:

1. use Collections to store your data as you read through each column,
   building up a list of data relevant to each user.
2. Create a worksheet for each user, and write out of the user's collection to the appropriate worksheet.
3. Use Excel's sorting function to put the list in order.
4. Transpose the sorted list to the FinalResults sheet.

The code is as follows (note this currently reads all columns but only writes out UserA. I will leave it to you to extend the code to cover the other users):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferTimeCodes()
    Dim UserA As New Collection
    Dim UserB As New Collection
    Dim UserC As New Collection
    Dim sh As New Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim ColCount, RowCount As Integer
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim WrdArray() As String


    Set sh = Sheets("Timesheet")
    RowCount = 0
    ColCount = 1

    'Loop through the Process A User column and build up list of timecodes
    ' for users who used Process A
    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        'Check for User A
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "A" Then
            'Timecode is one cell to the right
            ' Join the two pieces of data together to ensure alignment
            'Note the "A" is fixed because it is Process A
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserA.Add Msg
        End If
        'Check for User B
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "B" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserB.Add Msg
        End If
        'Check for User C
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "C" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserC.Add Msg
        End If
        'Check for the end of the column
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Next rw

    RowCount = 0
    ColCount = 3

    'Loop through the Process B User column and build up list of timecodes
    ' for users who used Process B
    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "A" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserA.Add Msg
        End If
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "B" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserB.Add Msg
        End If
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "C" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserC.Add Msg
        End If
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Next rw

    RowCount = 0
    ColCount = 5

    'Loop through the Process C User column and build up list of timecodes
    ' for users who used Process C
    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "A" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserA.Add Msg
        End If
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "B" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserB.Add Msg
        End If
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "C" Then
            Msg = "A," & sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Offset(0, 1).Value
            UserC.Add Msg
        End If
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, ColCount).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Next rw

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "UserA"
    Set sh = Sheets("UserA")
    For RowCount = 0 To UserA.Count - 1
        WrdArray() = Split(UserA(RowCount + 1), ",")
        sh.Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = WrdArray(0)
        sh.Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = WrdArray(1)
    Next RowCount
    sh.UsedRange.Sort key1:=Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    sh.UsedRange.Columns(2).Copy
    Worksheets("FinalResults").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```